# Using Quadratic Terms vs Linear & Quadratic Simultaneously

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-analysis

Im working on a data analytics lab where we have to produce the best model to predict from a data set.

From my understanding a regression model that includes interaction terms (quadratic terms) as predictors along with the linear terms is more general than a corresponding model that only uses the linear terms.

When would just using the linear terms perform better than using both?

My impression is that if the individual terms aren't very related then adding more terms that relates them would just clutter the data. Is this the case? I'm not sure I'm understanding the concept.

Comment: not a programming, but a data analysis / ML question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry, I thought my tags would take care of that. Is there somewhere else I should post the question?

Comment: there's a data analysis/statistics/ml sister side on the stackexchange network...

Answer (score -1):

There is a lot of detail that could be given on this, but I will keep to a brief response.  Will demonstrate with some very simple R code and using Adjusted R squared:

```
x <- c(3, 4, 5, 7, 10)
y <- c(5, 8, 9, 11, 18)
plot(x, y)

yfit <- lm(y ~ x)
rsquaredfit <- summary(yfit)$adj.r.squared
rsquaredfit

yfitquad <- lm(y ~ x + I(x ^ 2))
yfitquad
rsquaredfitquad <- summary(yfitquad)$adj.r.squared
rsquaredfitquad
```

Note the lower adjusted R squared for the model with the quadratic term.  Here the true relationship is clearly linear and the quadratic term overfits.